# Compilation of libssh2 for the iPhone fails

Tags: iphone, objective-c, libssh

Currently i'm trying to compile libssh2 to run on the iPhone.

On my research i've found [those instructions](http://sites.google.com/site/olipion/cross-compilation/libssh2) how to compile it. But when i try it i always get

`configure: error: C preprocessor "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/cpp" fails sanity check`

any ideas whats wrong? or can any one who already compiled libssh2 upload the compiled files for me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS?

```
export CFLAGS=-m32
export CPPFLAGS=-m32
```